# 180° FOV camera with RAW output for under US$300

Tags: camera

I'm looking for a photo camera capable of taking photos of the whole sky from zenith to the horizon. The camera must:

- have field of view at least 180°
- provide RAW format photos
- be controllable from a PC (to set exposure, trigger the shutter etc.)
- have "bulb" shutter mode
- have low enough noise to be usable for easily shooting visible stars.

Maximum desirable price is about US$300.

Currently I have Canon 1100D (not counting against the max price) which satisfies almost all the above points, but doesn't have any wide-enough-angle lens. Since it has a cropped sensor, I'm not sure I'll be able to find any fisheye lens to get 180° FOV. But if you know of a cheap enough suitable lens, it'll be a good answer. Otherwise, I expect some solution independent of my existing camera.

Comment: $150 is a pretty tight budget for what you're looking for. If you're able to stretch it, you might give yourself a better chance of a result.